# PMF of coin toss experiment

Tags: probability

A coin has probability $0.7$ of coming up heads. The coin is flipped $10$ times.
Let $X$ be the number of heads that come up. Write out $P(X = k)$ for every value of $k$ from
$0$ to $10$. Approximate each value to five decimal places. Which value of $k$ has the highest
probability?

This is the PMF for this problem
$$
P_X(k)=
\begin{cases}
\left(\frac7{10}\right)&\text{if } k=1\\
\left(\frac7{10}\right)^2 &\text{if }k=2 \\
\,\,\,\,\vdots & \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\vdots\\
\left(\frac7{10}\right)^{10} & \text{if } k=10
\end{cases}
$$

I think I'm supposed to use the binomial theorem to answer it? That's what we are talking about in my class so it makes sense. I would appreciate a hint to guide me through the problem. Thanks.

Comment: The function you wrote gives the probability of getting all heads in the first $k$ tosses, not the probability of getting exactly $k$ heads among 10 tosses. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

Comment: Also note that $0.7\ne\frac17$.

Comment: meant to type $1/10$. Thanks for bringing that to my attention

Comment: Clearly, I can't seem to avoid making these errors. I meant to make $0.7$ into $\frac7{10}$

Answer (score 1):

Just find numerically
$$k^*=\underset{k\in \{1,\ldots,10\}}{\text{argmax}}\ \ f(k)={10 \choose k} \left(\frac{7}{10}\right)^k\left(1-\frac{7}{10}\right)^{10-k}$$
Notice that $f(k)$ is de PDF of a Binomial$(n=10,p=7/10)$.

In R you could use, for instance,

```
(1:10)[which.max(dbinom(1:10,10,7/10))] 

[1] 7
```